# Is there a way to export a CSF/XSF file from 3ds Max?

Tags: animation, 3dsmax, avatar, vizard

I need to convert my avatars (format fbx) with motion capture animation into a cfg file for vizard to use. I could not find any programs that could convert the parts of my fbx file to file formats required to make a cfg file (CSF, CAF, CRF).

I've tried to send the file to 3ds Max and I tried to export the Skeletion, Mesh, Material etc. in different formats required to create a cfg file (CSF, CRF etc.) I installed the add on Cal3D exporter, but it seems it is not compatible with 3ds Max 2022/2023.
When I try to import the different files like the Skeleton I doesn't have the option to export it as a cfs file.
Does anyone know some other options how to make out of an fbx file a cfg, or make Cal3d compatible with newer versions of 3ds Max or some other ideas?